# Getting Max Value from an array

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to use an api from postcodeanywhere that calcuates the total travel time and distance for a particular journey, and I have got it working using the following code:

```
//Build URL Request
$url = "http://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/DistancesAndDirections/Interactive/Directions/v2.00/xmla.ws?";
$url .= "&Key=" . urlencode($Key);
$url .= "&Start=" . urlencode($Start);
$url .= "&Finish=" . urlencode($Finish);
$url .= "&DistanceType=" . urlencode($DistanceType);

//Make the request to Postcode Anywhere and parse the XML returned
$file = simplexml_load_file($url);

//Check for an error, if there is one then throw an exception
if ($file->Columns->Column->attributes()->Name == "Error") 
{
throw new Exception("[ID] " . $file->Rows->Row->attributes()->Error . " [DESCRIPTION] " . $file->Rows->Row->attributes()->Description . " [CAUSE] " . $file->Rows->Row->attributes()->Cause . " [RESOLUTION] " . $file->Rows->Row->attributes()->Resolution);
}

//Copy the data
if ( !empty($file->Rows) )
{
foreach ($file->Rows->Row as $item)
{
$Data[] = array('SegmentNumber'=>$item->attributes()->SegmentNumber,'StepNumber'=>$item->attributes()->StepNumber,'Action'=>$item->attributes()->Action,'Description'=>$item->attributes()->Description,'Road'=>$item->attributes()->Road,'StepTime'=>$item->attributes()->StepTime,'StepDistance'=>$item->attributes()->StepDistance,'TotalTime'=>$item->attributes()->TotalTime,'TotalDistance'=>$item->attributes()->TotalDistance);


$TotalDistance = ($item["TotalDistance"] * 0.000621371192);


echo $TotalDistance."<br>";
```

Which results in the following [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/7bl8ym)

The problem I am having is that the echo shows that it is displaying distance for each journey step, whereas I just want the max value.

I have tried `$TotalDistance = max($item["TotalDistance"])`. only to get the following error:

```
max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `$TotalDistance = max($item)`. and where you call it in your code?

Comment: Didnt work, could you explain with an example?

Comment: explained with live example link. check that in my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the max value:

```
$value = max($array);
```

Comment: You could just link the documentation

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is put the total distance into an array first, then grab the max. Like this:

```
$distance_array = new array();

foreach ($file->Rows->Row as $item)
{
    $Data[] = array('SegmentNumber'=>$item->attributes()->SegmentNumber,'StepNumber'=>$item->attributes()->StepNumber,'Action'=>$item->attributes()->Action,'Description'=>$item->attributes()->Description,'Road'=>$item->attributes()->Road,'StepTime'=>$item->attributes()->StepTime,'StepDistance'=>$item->attributes()->StepDistance,'TotalTime'=>$item->attributes()->TotalTime,'TotalDistance'=>$item->attributes()->TotalDistance);

    $TotalDistance = ($item["TotalDistance"] * 0.000621371192);

    array_push($distance_array, $TotalDistance); //add the distance to an array

}

echo max($distance_array);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

Comment: thanks tried that and got array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given